# Google Calendar API/PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have followed the directions exactly, copied code examples - I cannot get this to respond (write an event on a calendar).
Please help - if there is any help for me.  AFter 12 hours of working on this with a huge deadline of tomorrow, I'm about to pull my hair out.

On Google Developer Console, created a project and generated keys required.
The keys below are altered for safety.
None of the echos are showing except for the first one with the order number in it.
My programmer got this code to work, so I know it's OK - it's something set up wrong on the console, but I need a clue:

Full code - like I said, it's been tested and works on another project.

```
    if(isset($_GET['orderid']) )
    {
        $_SESSION['oid']= $_GET['orderid'];

    }
echo $_GET['orderid'];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API Project");
$client->setClientId('9999999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);

//$client->setDeveloperKey('AIxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); - SERVER APPS
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // - WEB APPS 


$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
 unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 echo $_GET['code'];
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
 header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .      $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['token'];
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
$calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
//print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

// database access is here and like I said, it is tested and working

```
echo "<center>Event has successfully added to Your Google Calendar...</center>";
unset($_SESSION['oid']);


} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Click Here for Google Authorization!</a>";
}
```

Comment: We need more than just "it does not work". How do you know that it does not work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: And, yeah, the code does not look "OK" to me. You are `echo`ing array values without making sure they are set; you do not deal with any possible errors; `$cal` is created but never used; you are `echo`ing stuff *after* a redirect. This code could fail in numerous ways.

Comment: There is no echoes past the orderid and no calendar entries and no message:
 if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
   echo "<center>Event has successfully added to Your Google Calendar...</center>";
    unset($_SESSION['oid']);
}

Comment: OK - I updated the code to the full code so you can see it all works great, but something in the console is set up wrong.  The instructions for that part are unspecific and OLD at best.

Comment: AFter moving the echoes around, I know that this line of code is what is broken:
 $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();

Comment: So that means it can't find my calendar, right?  I know it's there - I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add an event on Google Calendar (no other interactions), I think you should use the direct link :

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Your+event+title&dates=20140325T090000Z/20140325T100000Z&details=Your+event+description&location=Room+12&pli=1&uid&sf=true&output=xml

You just have to customize variables and escape non-URI characters.

** EDIT **

Do you successfully connect the user through OAuth 2?

** EDIT 2 **

Your code is working for me without the DB access :

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
    //print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 

    // DB ACCESS 

    echo "<center>Event has successfully added to Your Google Calendar...</center>";
    unset($_SESSION['oid']);
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Click Here for Google Authorization!</a>";
}
```

Julian

Comment: Well, it does read and render from a database table, kicked off from an order generation. I have to have the keys in a database because depending on the order, it could write to 20 different calendars.
Would this work?

Comment: So an order can have several hundred entries to 20 different calendars.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. So this solution is not really the best for you. I edited my answer with another question for you.

Comment: I know that this line of code is what is broken: $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();  I also know there are a ton of other posts for this error but not finding a solution.

Comment: I tried your code and I successfully obtained the : "Event has successfully added to Your Google Calendar..." message. What's your PHP version ?

Comment: Check in your db access code if you don't override a variable that you use later. $cal for example ;)